# Highest Scholarship vs Biggest Scholarship

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I want to convey that I received the highest amount of scholarship (For example: if scholarship amounts range from $1000 to $10000, I got $10000) given to the top 1 or 2% of the class. I want to write it as precisely as possible. What would be the apt sentence?

This is what I am thinking:

> Recipient of highest XYZ scholarship (Awarded to top 3% of incoming class)

Not sure if the word *highest* is appropriate.

Comment: Uh, *largest* ?

Comment: Recipient of largest xxx department scholarship amount (Awarded to top 3% of the incoming class) -
Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Go with largest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "highest" to compare relative monetary amounts.

For example, OED [definition IIIb](http://www.oed.com.offcampus.lib.washington.edu/view/Entry/86850?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=qKOYwv&):

> Of a price, rate, amount, percentage, etc.: having a large numerical value. Also: (of a commodity) high-priced, expensive, costly; (of money) lent out at a high rate of interest; (of a currency) having a relatively high exchange rate.

But "highest" in the context of "scholarship" also means "the best," for example, [this page](https://www.washington.edu/students/ugrad/advising/aif/highschol.html) from the University of Washington is titled "High Scholarship Recognition" and deals with dean's lists and Latin honors.

> **High Scholarship Recognition**
>
> Please refer to the General Catalog page on Dean's List for information about Quarterly Dean's List; Annual Dean's List; Baccalaureate Honors; Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, and President's Medals; and Honorary Societies.

In this context, I would read "highest scholarship" to mean the most prestigious scholarship offered, in terms of prerequisites. In other words, there's no scholarship for the top 1%. That said, it doesn't *necessarily* imply the money is the largest available (but it's likely); there could be a larger scholarship for *really good* football players, for instance.

If you want to emphasize how hard it was to get, "highest" is a good choice. If you only want to point out how much money it was, "biggest" or "largest" might be a slightly more accurate choice.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may sound awkward to you, the term "highest scholarship" is 100% correct. Here is the term "highest scholarship award" used by Florida Atlantic University on the page http://www.fau.edu/admissions/pdf/scholarships.pdf:

"Participants will be considered for our **highest scholarship awards**. Selected students will have completed an Honors College application or, if they received an invitation to join the Honors College, submitted a resume by December 15."

Largest/biggest scholarship is generally used to refer to the scholarship program as a whole.

To be as precise as possible go for:

**Recipient of highest dollar amount XYZ scholarship (Awarded to top 3% of incoming class).**